# Cannot extend Windows partition

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

I have created a 150 gigabyte partition for an extra operating system, but then decided I did not need it. Now I cannot extend my partition C:/Windows8_OS(NTFS), even though the 150 gigabyte partition is unallocated and formatted.

This is a picture of the current partitions.

[image: Screenshot]

I am using MiniTool Partition Wizard Free 9.1.

**My system:**

- System: Lenovo Y50-70
- Processor: Intel Core i7-4700HQ
- Ram: 8GB
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 860M
- Hard Drive: 1TB HDD with a 32GB SSD in the place of the disk drive

When I try to extend the **C:/Windows8_OS(NTFS)** partition, I get this, even though I have the 150GB unallocated.

[image: Screenshot]

Is this a problem with my hard drive, or should I be using a different software?

Thank you,

Wup

Comment: Tried removing the small "Other" partition after the C partition and then growing? Or first try with Windows' own partition resizing tools?

Comment: You can't have an unallocated formatted partition... Just saying :-P

Comment: This post is old, so I will comment only. Today version of MiniTool can resize partition, even if there is other one before free unallocated space. Also AOMEI and Ease Us work. Keep MiniTool version 10 or 11, they are still free. Not sure about version 12.

Answer (score 1):

@SamiKuhmonen has the right idea. Your photo shows a 1MB partition, unknown type, after your C: drive but before the unallocated space. Delete it (which will merge it into the unallocated space, and you should be fine.

Incidentally, Windows has it's own disk management tools. There's a command-line one, `diskpart`, which is quite powerful. There's also a nice, user-friendly GUI "Disk Management" utility `diskmgmt.msc`, which is similar to what's shown in your screenshots, but is built into Windows.

Comment: That worked, I did not know that the partitions had to be next to each other, which is an important piece of information, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, a partition must be contiguous. You can have a *logical volume* - something that the OS treats as a single drive - that is not contiguous, but actual partitions must be contiguous. You can't expand a partition unless the space next to it is unused.